# Trying to traverse through nested xml tags but recursive function does not traverse in full depth

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

I have following xml data in string format, which using `lxml` package of python, I am parsing into xml.

Now, I have to traverse through this xml data and generate an output in a specific format which will be something like this

```
<A xmlns="dfjdlfkdjflsd">
  <B>
    <B1>B_1</B1>
    <B2>B_2</B2>
    <B3>
      <B31>B3_1</B31>
      <B32>B3_2</B32>
      <B33>
        <B331>
          <B3311></B3311>
        </B331>
        <B332>
          <B3321></B3321>
        </B332>
      </B33>
      <B34>
        <B341>
          <B3411></B3411>
        </B341>
        <B342>
          <B3421></B3421>
        </B342>
      </B34>
      <B35>
        <B351>B35_1</B351>
        <B352>
          <B3521>
            <B35211></B35211>
            <B35211></B35212>
          </B3521>
        </B352>
      </B35>
      <B36>
        <B361>B36_1</B361>
        <B362>B36_2</B362>
      </B36>
    </B3>
  </B>
</A>
```

And I would like to have the output in the following format:

```
{
    'B1': 'B_1',
    'B2': 'B_2',
    'B3_B31': 'B3_1',
    'B3_B32': 'B3_2',
    'B3_B33_B331_B3311': '-',
    'B3_B33_B331_B3312': '-',
    'B3_B34_B341_B3411': '-',
    'B3_B34_B342_B3421': '-',
    'B3_B35_B351': 'B35_1',
    'B3_B35_B352_B3521_B35211': '-',
    'B3_B35_B352_B3521_B35212': '-',
    'B3_B36_B361': 'b36_1',
    'B3_B36_B361': 'B36_2',
}
```

Now, this is just an EXAMPLE. In real scenario, depth of each xml tag might be different. So, I decided to use the recursive approach. And this is so far I have came in terms of code:

```
class ParseXML:
    main_output = []
    output = {}

    def __init__(self, xml_input):
        parser = ET.XMLParser(recover=True)
        tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(xml_input, parser=parser))
        self.root = tree.getroot()

    def parse_outer_xml(self):
        for children in self.root:
            output = self.parse_xml(children, output={})
            self.main_output.append(output)
        return self.main_output

    def parse_xml(self, children, tag=None, output={}):
        if len(children):
            for child in children.getchildren():
                if child.tag.split('}')[1] in GLOBAL_DICT:
                    output['{0}_{1}'.format(tag, child.tag.split('}')[1]) if tag else child.tag.split('}')[1]] = child.text
                else:
                    if child.tag.split('}')[1] not in GLOBAL_EXCLUDE_DICT:
                        if len(child):
                            if children.tag.split('}')[1] == 'B':
                                tag = child.tag.split('}')[1]
                            else:
                                tag = "{0}_{1}".format(tag, child.tag.split('}')[1]) if tag else "{0}_{1}".format(children.tag.split('}')[1], child.tag.split('}')[1])
                            return self.parse_xml(child, tag, output)
                        else:
                            output['{0}_{1}'.format(tag, child.tag.split('}')[1]) if tag else child.tag.split('}')[1]] = child.text if child.text else "-"
        else:
            output['{0}_{1}'.format(tag, children.tag.split('}')[1]) if tag else children.tag.split('}')[1]] = children.text if children.text else "-"
        return output


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse = ParseXML(data)
    temp = parse.parse_outer_xml()
    pprint(temp)
```

I am getting this output when I run

```
[{'B1': 'B_1',
  'B2': 'B_2',
  'B3_B31': 'B3_1',
  'B3_B32': 'B3_2',
  'B3_B33_B331_B3311': '-'}]
```

But this code does not traverse to full depth. Can anyone look into this and provide some guidance on how to traverse through this xml data till full depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET, re
t = ET.fromstring(re.sub('\sxmlns\="\w+"', '', s_xml))
def flatten(t, p = []):
   if not (c:=list(t)):
      yield ('_'.join(p+[t.tag]), '-' if t.text is None else t.text)
   else:
      yield from [j for k in c for j in flatten(k, p+[t.tag])]

r = dict(j for k in list(t)[0] for j in flatten(k))
```

Output:

```
{'B1': 'B_1', 'B2': 'B_2', 'B3_B31': 'B3_1', 'B3_B32': 'B3_2', 'B3_B33_B331_B3311': '-', 'B3_B33_B332_B3321': '-', 'B3_B34_B341_B3411': '-', 'B3_B34_B342_B3421': '-', 'B3_B35_B351': 'B35_1', 'B3_B35_B352_B3521_B35211': '-', 'B3_B36_B361': 'B36_1', 'B3_B36_B362': 'B36_2'}
```

Comment: Can you look into it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69405350/handling-duplicate-xml-tags-while-converting-nested-xml-tags-to-list-of-dictiona?

Answer (score 1):

First, the sample xml in your question is not well formed. Assuming that's fixed, you first have to deal with the fact that your xml contains a namespace declaration. So all in all, something like the below (using lxml) should get you at least close enough:

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.XML([your xml above, well formed])

#remove the namespace
for elem in doc.getiterator():
    elem.tag = etree.QName(elem).localname

#from here, get the path of each element and massage it a bit to fit what I believe 
#are your requirements 
tree = etree.ElementTree(doc)    
targets = []
for e in doc.iter():
        path = tree.getpath(e).replace("/A/B/","").replace("/","_") 
        if "A" not in path:        
            if e.text is not None and len(e.text.strip())>0:
                targets.append(path+" : "+e.text.strip())
            else:
                if not e.text:
                    targets.append(path+": -")
                
for target in targets:
    print(target)
```

Output (at least from the sample xml) should be your expected output.